# Multiple Boxplot's using a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, boxplot

I have a large dataset and I have divided the Dataset into small subsets of 0.1 (from 0 to 100). I want to plot a boxplot for this (same as a lineplot but with boxplot) from 0 to 100.

For generating/reducing the data (originally in billions), I have run a loop, as below:

```py
a = np.array(Treecover.where(low)).flatten()   # Treecover less than 25 only/low
b = np.array(RZSC.where(low)).flatten()        
Low_TC_data = pd.DataFrame({'Treecover': a, 'RZSC': b})
Low_TC_data_NaN = Low_TC_data.dropna()

Tree = []
Mean = []
Max = []
Min = []
Median = []
for i in np.arange(0,1,0.1):
    Tree.append(i)
    a = 0
    a = Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.1))).dropna()
    Mean.append(a.mean())
    Min.append(a.min())
    Max.append(a.max())  
    Median.append(a.median())
```

Then I plotted a scatter plot to visulaize the data.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

plt.scatter(Tree, Mean, s = 500)
plt.scatter(Tree, Median,color = 'red', s = 500)
plt.fill_between(Tree, Min, Max, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

I have tried to plot first 11 boxplots by writting them as follows:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
i = 0
green_diamond = dict(markerfacecolor='w', marker='D')
plt.boxplot((Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.1))).dropna(),
            Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.1)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.2))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.2)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.3))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.3)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.4))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.4)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.5))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.5)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.6))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.6)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.7))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.7)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.8))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.8)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.9))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+0.9)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+1))).dropna(),
           Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+1)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+1.1))).dropna()),
           flierprops=green_diamond);
# and this code can go on to 
# ....Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i+24.9)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+25))).dropna()
# For first 250 boxplots
```

[image]

*X-axis above is 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.......1.*

I want to have a boxplot of 100 such altogather (or even 1000 altogather), if possible.

I tried one failed attempt to do this using the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 10))

data = [(Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i)) & (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.1))).dropna()) for i in np.arange(0,1,0.1)]
[plt.boxplot(np.array(data[i]).ravel()) for i in range(5)];
```

[image]

*The values in this also seems to be a bit strange. And does not follow the second figure.*

I want boxplot for all my data steps. Basically, I want the second figure code, to be shorter (concise) for the same results as Fig. 2, and can be used when there are about 100 values on the x-axis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tweaked a bit around and rather than looping the boxplot, I looped the data itself.

The code looks a bit like this:

```py
data = [[Low_TC_data_NaN['RZSC'].where((Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']>=(i)) & 
                                      (Low_TC_data_NaN['Treecover']<(i+0.1))).dropna()] for i in np.arange(0,25,0.1)]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
green_diamond = dict(markerfacecolor='w', marker='D')
plt.boxplot(np.array(data).squeeze(), flierprops=green_diamond);
plt.ylim(0,4000)
```

And the results were like this:
[image]

*X-axis seems to have values between 0-25 (a total of 250 box plots).*